# Best way to dynamically render different views in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am relatively new to Android development and I am confused on what would be the best way to dynamically render different views in Android.

I have an activity that searches through a database of information and displays the results to the user with an expandable list view. As it currently stands, the xml layout file just has an expandable list view. This element is initially blank but is then populated when the user performs a search.

My issue is I would like to show a message to the user(Instructions) if the expandable list view has not yet been populated, and I am not sure what the best way to do this is? Should I dynamically add another view at runtime or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: What are those different views you are talking about? ImageViews? TextViews? Those in your ListView I mean

Comment: Usually overlay with a ProgressView and hide it afterwards the entire layout or use a AlertDialog with a ProgressView and dismiss it when done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to accomplish this is with 2 separate views in your layout. First the an explanation text will appear and once you get data you can hide the view and show the list.

Below is the core of what you can do:

**Layout:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" > 

     <TextView
          android:id="@+id/explanation_view"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:text="@string/explanation"
          android:visibility="visible"/>

     <ListView
          android:id="@+id/list_view"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:visibility="gone"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

**Java:**

```
void onData(Data data) {
    explanationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: This is very straightforward and solves my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I thing what you can do is create a view (`ImageView, Button, ProgressBar, whatever you want to use to display a message for user`) in your xml file an show it before you get the data from the `Data Base`. Once you get data hide the View.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a so-called "empty view". Empty views are views that get shown to the user in place of a list/grid when there's no data loaded into them. They're a nice, user-friendly way of telling the user that there's no content to show. In your use case, they can also serve as place for instructions to the user about how to get data loaded.

There are a number of ways of implementing this (it's hard to know which one is easiest or best for you without seeing more of your code), but the general concept is the same: Add an "empty view" to your layout XML file. It can be anything you want, but to give you an idea of what most look like, check out what the [Material Design guidelines](https://material.io/design/communication/empty-states.html#) have to say about this topic. Give the empty view an initial visibility of `View.VISIBLE`, then set it to `View.GONE` or `View.VISIBLE` each time you update your list's `ExpandableListAdapter`. If the adapter is empty, set the empty view to `View.VISIBLE`, otherwise set it to `View.GONE`. If you'd like more specific guidance (e.g. some actual code), we'll have to see more of your code that shows how data is being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can take frame layout as the root layout and add a layout you would like to show when the list is empty , and then you list as the second child . And you need to manage their visibity on differnt events.

Note :- While using frame layouts the last child is shown above the other children if these have a same layout_gravity.In Frame Layout you can align view by setting its layout_gravity attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to use Fragments together with LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.
While the request is being made, and if it does not return any data, the EmptyView will be shown, in the case that you dont have an Internet connection, the EmptyView will also be shown.
When the LoaderManager has some data, it will automatically replace the EmptyView with the Listview:

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
   private ViewPager viewPager;
   private CategoryAdapter adapter;

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listados);
        ToolBar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        adapter = new CategoryAdapter(fragmentManager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
}
```

The CategoryAdapter class could be something like this:

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public CategoryAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new ListFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

The Fragment class could be something like this:

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks <List <Item >> {

    private View rootView;
    private ListView listView;
    private ListItemAdapter listItemAdapter;
    private List <Item> listItem = new ArrayList <> ();
    public static final int LOADER_ID = 0;
    
    public ListFragment () {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView (final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        rootView = inflater.inflate (R.layout.component_list, container, false);
        listItemAdapter = new ListItemAdapter (getActivity (), listItem);
        listView = rootView.findViewById (R.id.list);
        emptyImageView = rootView.findViewById (R.id.empty_list_item);
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
        getContext (). getSystemService (Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo ();
        if (networkInfo! = null && networkInfo.isConnected ()) {
            if (getActivity (). getSupportLoaderManager (). getLoader (LOADER_ID) == null) {
                listView.setEmptyView (rootView.findViewById (R.id.connection_progress));
                getActivity (). getSupportLoaderManager (). initLoader (LOADER_ID, null, this) .forceLoad ();
            } else {
                listView.setEmptyView (rootView.findViewById (R.id.empty_list_item));
            }
        } else {
            listView.setEmptyView (rootView.findViewById (R.id.no_connection_list_item));
        }
        listView.setAdapter (listItemAdapter);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public Loader <List <Item >> onCreateLoader (int id, Bundle args) {
        return new ItemLoader (getActivity (), LOADER_ID);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished (Loader <List <Item >> loader, List <Item> data) {
        if (data.size () == 0) {
            listView.setEmptyView (rootView.findViewById (R.id.empty_list_item));
        } else {
          listItem = data;
          listItemAdapter.setListItem (data);
          listView.setAdapter (listItemAdapter);
          listItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset (Loader <List <Item >> loader) {
        listItemAdapter.setListItem (new ArrayList <Item> ());
    }

}
```

The Adapter class could be something like this:

```
public class ListItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {
    Context context;
    public static List<Item> listItem = new ArrayList<>();
    private Item item = new Item();
    public ListItemAdapter(Context context, List<Item> listItem) {
        super(context, 0, listItem);
        this.context = context;
        this.listItem = listItem;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView titleTextView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Resources res = context.getResources();
        ViewHolder holder;
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item_layout, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            listItemView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) listItemView.getTag();
        }
holder.titleTextView.setText(res.getString(R.string.title_text,item.getTitle()));
        return listItemView;
    }

    public void setListItem(List<Item> data) {
        listItem.clear();
        listItem.addAll(data);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```